# How to load Underscore library with RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, requirejs

```
require(['underscore'], function ($, _) {
  ...
});
```

Doesnt work! (`_` is not a function)

How to manage it?

Answer (score 7):

Note that underscore.js doesn't register itself as an AMD module (though it did for a brief time in earlier versions), thus it can't be used in a require() call without some configuration using "shim:" like so:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'lib/jquery.min',
        underscore: 'lib/underscore-min'
    }
    shim: {
        "underscore": {
            exports: "_"
        }
    }
});
```

See the docs at: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Before `shim:` was added to require.js, you could do something similar with the plugin use.js (in case you need to use an older version of require.js).

As of this writing, the current version of require.js is 2.1.8.

Alternatively, you can use lodash.js as a drop-in replacement for underscore.js - it does register itself as an AMD module, so you can use it with no extra config: http://lodash.com/

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is the order of args passed in to your callback.

Should be:

```
require(['underscore'], function (_, $) {
 ...
});
```

Also you need to be using underscore version 1.2.1 which added this functionality.

Comment: definitely the order is a part of the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
require(["underscore"], function() { 
  console.log(_ === window._);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it all depends where the script is based.
since i don't see you specified a baseUrl, the baseUrl will be the default,
that means, either 2 things:

1. your script is directly inside a html file, and in your case it
   will thus look for underscore.js in the same directory of the html
   file
2. your script is in a javascript file referenced by your html
   file, it will now search for underscore.js in the directory of your
   custom javascript file.

check if the underscore.js is actually there.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the checkpoints for you to make sure what you need works

1. Get [require-jquery.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#get) and put it to your `/js-root` dir
2. Add to your HTML, right before the closing `</body>` tag: `<script data-main="/js-root/main-js-file-name" src="/js-root/require-jquery.js"></script>`
3. Get [underscore adapted for AMD](https://github.com/amdjs/underscore), and put it to `/js-root` dir as well
4. In `main-js-file-name.js`

write:

```
require(["jquery", "underscore"], function ($, _) {
    ...
});
```

Similarly, in your non-main AMD JS files, when defining a module, to use `_`, write:

```
define(["jquery", "underscore"], function ($, _) {
    ...
    return theModuleObjectOrFunction;
});
```